how to add red labels to each empty/non selected filed on clicking submit button
the form should showcase red labels if i leave the fields empty for each individual field. but here when i click submit the form submitted successfully pop up shows and and the entire form clears up even when the entire form was empty . I feel the captcha is causing the issue with the overall logic but how do i fix that.
import React, { useState,useEffect,useRef } from 'react';
import { Headings } from '../../components';
import './Contact.css';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import axios from 'axios';

import { Toast } from 'react-bootstrap';


const Contact = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [captchaText, setCaptchaText] = useState(''); 
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState(''); 
  const canvasRef = useRef(null); 
  const [showToast, setShowToast] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => { 
      const canvas = canvasRef.current; 
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
      initializeCaptcha(ctx); 
  }, []); 
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    companyName: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    message: '',
    solutionType: '',
    agreeToCommunications: false,
    agreeToStoreData: false
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const generateRandomChar = (min, max) => 
        String.fromCharCode(Math.floor 
            (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)); 
  
    const generateCaptchaText = () => { 
        let captcha = ''; 
        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
            captcha += generateRandomChar(65, 90); 
            captcha += generateRandomChar(97, 122); 
            captcha += generateRandomChar(48, 57); 
        } 
        return captcha.split('').sort( 
            () => Math.random() - 0.5).join(''); 
    }; 
  
    const drawCaptchaOnCanvas = (ctx, captcha) => { 
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); 
        const textColors = ['rgb(0,0,0)', 'rgb(130,130,130)']; 
        const letterSpace = 150 / captcha.length; 
        for (let i = 0; i < captcha.length; i++) { 
            const xInitialSpace = 25; 
            ctx.font = '20px Roboto Mono'; 
            ctx.fillStyle = textColors[Math.floor( 
                Math.random() * 2)]; 
            ctx.fillText( 
                captcha[i], 
                xInitialSpace + i * letterSpace, 
                  
                // Randomize Y position slightly 
                Math.floor(Math.random() * 16 + 25), 
                100 
            ); 
        } 
    }; 
  
    const initializeCaptcha = (ctx) => { 
        setUserInput(''); 
        const newCaptcha = generateCaptchaText(); 
        setCaptchaText(newCaptcha); 
        drawCaptchaOnCanvas(ctx, newCaptcha); 
    }; 
  
    const handleUserInputChange = (e) => { 
        setUserInput(e.target.value); 
    }; 
  
    const handleCaptchaSubmit = () => { 
        if (userInput === captchaText) { 
          setShowToast(true);
          // Clear form fields after successful submission
     ;
        } else { 
            alert('Incorrect Captcha'); 
            const canvas = canvasRef.current; 
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
            initializeCaptcha(ctx); 
        } 
    }; 

    
 
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();





    try {
      // Send form data to backend API
      const response = await axios.post('https://orelse.ai/api/contact', formData);
      console.log('Form submission successful:', response.data);
      
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Form submission error:', error);
    }
  };


  const handlePhoneChange = (value) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, phoneNumber: value });
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="section-padding" id="contact">
      <Headings title={t("Contact Us")} text={t("Let's Discuss the Best Solution for You")} />
<div className="contact-divider" style={{display:'flex'}}>
<div className="col-md-4" style={{padding:'60px' ,backgroundColor:'#f3f3f3' }}>
<h1 className='title'>Invest in nature</h1>
<p>Questions or requests for orelse? Our team is here to help. Tell us a little about your needs to be directed to the appropriate team.</p>
</div> 
<div className="col-md-8">
      <div className="contact" >
      
        <div className="row">
          <div className="formdetails">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>


            
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: '20px' }}>
    
    <input
      className="form-control"
      type="text"
      placeholder={t("First Name")}
      name="firstName"
      value={formData.firstName}
      onChange={handleChange}
      required
    />
  </div>
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: '20px' }}>
   
    <input
      className="form-control"
      type="text"
      placeholder={t("Last Name")}
      name="lastName"
      value={formData.lastName}
      onChange={handleChange}
      required
    />
  </div>
</div>

<div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: '20px' }}>
   
    <input
      className="form-control"
      type="email"
      placeholder={t("Email")}
      name="email"
      value={formData.email}
      onChange={handleChange}
      required
    />
  </div>
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: '20px' }}>
    
    <input
      className="form-control"
      type="text"
      placeholder={t("Company Name")}
      name="companyName"
      value={formData.companyName}
      onChange={handleChange}
      required
    />
  </div>
</div>






<div style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: '20px' }}>
 
  <input
    className="form-control"
    type="tel"
    placeholder={t("Phone Number")}
    name="phoneNumber"
    value={formData.phoneNumber}
    onChange={handleChange}
    required
  />
</div>



                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="Textarea1">{t("Message*")}</label>
                    <textarea
                      className="form-control"
                      id="Textareamessage"
                      rows="3"
                      name="message"
                      value={formData.message}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      required
                    ></textarea>
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="solutionType">{t("Select Solution Type")}</label>
                    <select
                      className="form-control"
                      id="solutionType"
                      name="solutionType"
                      value={formData.solutionType}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    >
                      <option value="">{t("Select Solution Type")}</option>
                      <option value="Measuring my emissions">{t("Measuring my emissions")}</option>
                      <option value="Sourcing sustainable grain">{t("Sourcing sustainable grain")}</option>
                      <option value="Creating a custom sustainable program">{t("Creating a custom sustainable program")}</option>
                      <option value="Purchasing carbon offsets">{t("Purchasing carbon offsets")}</option>
                      <option value="Transaction tooling">{t("Transaction tooling")}</option>
                      <option value="Scientific Collaboration">{t("Scientific Collaboration")}</option>
                      <option value="MRV Engine">{t("MRV Engine")}</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group checkbox-group">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id="checkbox"
                      name="agreeToCommunications"
                      checked={formData.agreeToCommunications}
                      onChange={() => setFormData({ ...formData, agreeToCommunications: !formData.agreeToCommunications })}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="checkbox">{t("I agree to receive other communications from orelse Solutions")}</label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group checkbox-group">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id="checkbox2"
                      name="agreeToStoreData"
                      checked={formData.agreeToStoreData}
                      onChange={() => setFormData({ ...formData, agreeToStoreData: !formData.agreeToStoreData })}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="checkbox2">{t("I agree to orelse to store and process my personal data")}</label>
                  </div>
                  <div> 
             
             
                  <label style={{  marginTop:'20px',minWidth: '130px' }}>{t("Captcha Verification")}</label>
         <div className="container-captcha"> 
             <div className="wrapper-captcha"> 
                 <canvas ref={canvasRef} 
                     width="200"
                     height="70"> 

                 </canvas> 
                 <button id="reload-button" onClick={ 
                     () => initializeCaptcha( 
                         canvasRef.current.getContext('2d'))}> 
                     Reload 
                 </button> 
             </div> 
             <input 
              className="form-control"
                 type="text"
                 id="user-input"
                 placeholder="Enter the text in the image"
                 value={userInput} 
                 onChange={handleUserInputChange}/> 
                   
             
         </div> 
     </div> 
     <button type="submit" className="btn-orelse-contact" onClick={handleCaptchaSubmit}>  {t("Submit")}</button>
          
         </form>

         <Toast
  show={showToast}
  onClose={() => setShowToast(false)}
  delay={5000}
  autohide
  position="top-end" // Position the toast on the top right corner
>
  <Toast.Header>
    <strong className="mr-auto">Success</strong>
  </Toast.Header>
  <Toast.Body>Form submitted successfully!</Toast.Body>
</Toast>
       </div>

       </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;

I also tried validating individual fields where i checked if that particular field was empty string and if yes show the error but it still wont work
